# Differential Equation $y'=\frac{1}{x^2-1}, y(0)=0$, am I missing something?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm encountering a singularity of sorts when working out this D.E. It seems like a very straight forward problem and, assuming I'm going wrong, I'm wondering where.

The problem: Solve the initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2-1}, y(0)=0$ and determine the interval of the independent variable on which the solution is defined.

Attempted solution: integrating w.r.t. x we have $\int_{x_0}^xy'dx=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{1}{t^2-1}dt\implies\int_{y_0}^yds=\int_0^x\frac{1}{(t-1)(t+1)}dt$ by change of variable formula. Then, by partial fraction decomposition $$\frac{1}{(t-1)(t+1)}=\frac{A}{t-1}+\frac{B}{t+1}\implies1=(A+B)t+A-B$$Therefore we see that $A=\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=-\frac{1}{2}$. Now our equation is $$y-y(0)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{2(t-1)}-\frac{1}{2(t+1)}dt=\left.\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)\right|_0^x=\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\mathrm{ln}(-1)\right]$$This is problem since $\mathrm{ln}(-1)\notin\mathbb{R}$ so I'm not really sure where to go from here. Wolfram says I'm doing the integral wrong and that it should be $\mathrm{ln}(1-x)$ instead of $\mathrm{ln}(x-1)$.

Anyways, any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: The reason for picking $\ln(1-x)$ is that $0 < x < 1$ so $\ln(x-1)$ is not defined. Note that both functions have the same derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$ \int \frac{1}{x} \, \text{d}x = \log |x| + C $$

Also it is better to use a different variable for the differential and the upper limit. I would write

$$ \int_{x_0}^x \frac{dy}{dt} \, \text{d}t = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{t^2 - 1} \, \text{d}t $$

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks!